# Python Error while going through a contour : tuple index out of range

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I'm trying to code a piece of code to check if a contour (obtained using cv2.FindContour) is touching the border of an image or not. The contour is a tuple object.

So far here is what my code looks like :

```
for a in range(len(contours)):
     contoursNew = []
     if not np.any(contours[a][:,0,:]) == 0 \
        or not np.any(contours[a][:,0,0]) == (np.size(self.imageDeBase, 1)-1) \
        or not np.any(contours[a][:,0,0]) == (np.size(self.imageDeBase, 0)-1) :
          contoursNew.append(contours[a])
                    
     contours = tuple(contoursNew)
```

This is supposed to compare the coordinates (x;y) of each point of the contour to see if any of them is on one of the borders of the image. if none is on the border, then we save the contour in contourNew which is a list and after the loop is completed, we make it a tuple.

However, this code won't work : Here is the error the terminal will return :

```
    if np.any(contours[a][:,0,:]) == 0 \

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I tried to print contours[a] to see how it's like but I had the same error, meaning **the part that doesn't work is** `contours[a]`. Probably I didn't manipulated the tuple right, but I don't know what to do then.

Can someone help me please ? Thank you !!

EDIT : about `cv2.findContour()` this is what the documentation says :
*This method returns two values. contours, and hierarchy. contours is a Python list of all the contours in the image. Each individual contour is a Numpy array of (x,y) coordinates of boundary points of the object.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following image with 3 contours to illustrate how to draw those **not** present on the borders:

[image]

```
# Reading the image, obtaining binary image and finding contours:
img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\524316\Desktop\Stack\c1.png')
img2 = img.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

Every contour is of the shape `(number_of_points, 1, 2)`. In the following I first reshape every contour array to `(number_of_points, 2)` making it easier to understand. Every reshaped contour is stored in `c_modified`. Next I check whether atleast one point of each contour is present on either boundaries of the image using `np.any()`. If they are not, draw them:

```
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    c_modified = c.reshape(len(contours[i]), 2)
    if not((np.any(c_modified[:,0] == img.shape[0] - 1)) |    # is any point in contour present on left boundary of image
           (np.any(c_modified[:,1] == img.shape[0] - 1)) |    # is any point in contour present on top boundary of image
           (np.any(c_modified[:,0] == img.shape[1] - 1)) |    # is any point in contour present on right boundary of image
           (np.any(c_modified[:,1] == img.shape[1] - 1))):    # is any point in contour present on bottom boundary of image
        
        img2 = cv2.drawContours(img2, [c], -1, (0, 255, 255), 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```python
    for contour in contours:
         contoursNew = []
         if not np.any(contour[:,0,:]) == 0 \
            or not np.any(contour[:,0,0]) == (np.size(self.imageDeBase, 1)-1) \
            or not np.any(contour[:,0,0]) == (np.size(self.imageDeBase, 0)-1) :
              contoursNew.append(contour)
                        
         contours = tuple(contoursNew)
```

And I'm not sure about your comparison, np.any() returns a boolean but you are comparing it with int and tuple. Maybe it should be something like this?

```python
 if not np.any(contour[:,0,:] == 0) \
            or not np.any(contour[:,0,0] == (np.size(self.imageDeBase, 1)-1)) \
            or not np.any(contour[:,0,0] == (np.size(self.imageDeBase, 0)-1)) :
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Indeed my parenthesis is wrong, it should be np.any(contour[:,0,:] == 0) instead ! Thank you for highlighting this ! In the end, I found the source of the error, it was an incremental error : contours = tuple(contoursNew) should be out of the for loop and not inside of it ! Thanks !